# installing logstash and supplying configuration as service in Fedora 25

Tags: logstash, fedora-25

I have installed logstash from zip file (https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash/logstash-5.5.2.tar.gz) and run below command I have option to pass the custom configuration.

```
 sudo logstash-5.5.2/bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

But when I have downloaded [logstash-5.5.2.rpm] (https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash/logstash-5.5.2.rpm) and installed it  using below command, I'm not sure how to pass the custom configuration.

```
sudo dnf install Downloads/logstash-5.5.2.rpm
```

The command to start the logstash is

```
sudo systemctl start logstash
```

Comment: This page might help you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/running-logstash.html. In short, you'll have to run logstash as a service.

Comment: Or you can just find the install directory of logstash and use the same command.